# Connect Mac OS X 10.2 to shared Windows USB external disk?

Tags: windows-xp, mac, network-shares

I have a Windows XP machine with an external (NTFS) USB disk which I have shared. I'd like access to this from a Mac (running OS-X 10.2.8). If I use 'Connect to server...' to connect to the Windows machine, I only see the shared documents folder and not the shared external disk.
How can I set up the Mac to get access to this drive?

Edit - I've previously tried co connect the drive directly (which would be the preferred solution) but NTFS seems to require a later version of OS-X. Have also tried formatting as FAT32.

It might well be that the only sensible solution it to upgrade the OS...

Comment: If you browse to the xp machine from it's own network neighborhood in explorer can you see the share?

Comment: Yep, can see it from Windows as '\\computername\External Disk'

Comment: Try "connect to server"  using that drive path.

Comment: No luck with smb://computername/sharename

Answer (score 1):

[ntfs-3g](http://www.ntfs-3g.org/) works great (aka: just put the usbstick into your mac)

Comment: Unfortunately NTFS-3G needs a minimum of OS-X 10.4

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfsosx/files/

Comment: ntfosx only gives read only access unfortunately and hasn't been touched since 2003. The readme is a bit worrying: "This is a pre-release version... All kinds of nasty things could happen including... file system corruption..."